# How to create a table for legend of a Stacked Chart in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

This is javascript code of stack chart in highchart-

```
 legend: {
 align: 'right',
 x: -70,
 verticalAlign: 'top',
 y: 20,
 floating: true,
 backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
 borderColor: '#CCC',
 borderWidth: 1,
 shadow: false
},
```

Here are series of my data-

```
series: [{
        name: 'A',
        data: [5]
    }, {
        name: 'B',
        data: [2]
    }, {
        name: 'C',
        data: [3]
    }]
```

Is it possible to show the legend of above data of a Highcharts (stacked Chart) in a table format ?

Comment: What's "table format" mean?  Can you draw a picture of what you are after?

Comment: Can you please attach screenshot,i really dont understand "table format"

Comment: If I understand correctly, something like
[this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MxkrN.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

**Highcharts (stacked Chart) in a table format**

http://jsfiddle.net/ntg7qz3q/1/

working fiddle

```
 $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Stacked bar chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['A', 'B', 'C']
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Total fruit consumption'
                }
            },
            legend: {
     align: 'right',
     x: -70,
     verticalAlign: 'top',
     y: 20,
     floating: true,
     backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
     borderColor: '#CCC',
     borderWidth: 1,
     shadow: false
    },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    stacking: 'normal'
                }
            },
            series: [{
            name: 'A',
            data: [5]
        }, {
            name: 'B',
            data: [2]
        }, {
            name: 'C',
            data: [3]
        }]
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is it possible to show the legend of above data of a Highcharts (stacked Chart) in a table format ?