# Highchart with Table

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

Is there highchart framework already exists when chart and table co-exists. For example as shown below.
[image]

I found few links but it didn't solved the problem.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246973/datatable-inside-highcharts-pie-chart)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033536/how-to-create-a-table-for-legend-of-a-stacked-chart-in-highcharts/27853695#27853695)

Comment: See http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed

Comment: Second solution is something like [this](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#add-data-table)